# Gradient following the shape of a face

Tags: materials, node-editor

In blender 2.79, I was able to create a gradient following the shape of a face (like a ngon circle with 8 edges) using the parametric output of the Geometry node plug into the quadratic gradient.

But it appears that it was a bug in 2.79 that has been corrected in 2.8.

Is there a way to reproduce this gradient using the node system in 2.8 ?

Thanks for your attention.

[image]

Edit :
I find this way to have a nice gradient with corners (I don't want a spherical gradient), but it doesn't follow the shape of the face, unfortunately :
[image]
[image]